# WP7 Using TransitioningContentControl for different forward and back animations

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm using the TransitioningContentControl to create animations for navigating between pages. I used this blog post as my guide: http://wildermuth.com/2010/07/16/Bring_Back_Page_Transitions_to_the_Windows_Phone_List_Application_Template

I also found this post that does something very similar: http://www.slickthought.net/post/2010/04/26/Simplifying-Page-Transitions-in-Windows-Phone-7-Silverlight-Applications.aspx

I was able to create navigation animations, but they are the same whether you go forward or backward in the app. I want to create opposite animations depending on navigation. If the user is moving forward, the transition is toward them (like flipping a book to the next page). If the user is moving backward, the transition is the opposite.

I can't find any documentation for this control, just examples. Everything I've seen targets "DefaultTransition", but I'm wondering if there is something like "ForwardTransition" and "BackwardTransition".

Comment: Have you tried Peter Torr's AnimatingFrame alternative? If I recall correctly, it allows you to specify the in/back animations for each page: http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/kevin_marshall/archive/2010/05/12/windows-phone-7-prototype-002-animated-page-transitions-writeable-bitmaps.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at it while investigating, but never got it to work with the final release tools. I'll take another look at it, since it seems there's nothing in TransitioningContentControl that can perform this behavior.

Comment: I remember now why I never got it to work. I fixed the issues between beta and final release, but there is a casting exception at run time that never could have worked. I wonder if they just uploaded the wrong code for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has released tools to do the page flipping animations in their latest update to the WP7 Silverlight toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

The TransitioningContentControl only knows about Current and Previous content. So it doesn't have any sense of "forward" or "backward" navigation. You could try defining two different VisualStates - ("NavigateForward" and "NavigateBackward") with opposite animations and then dynamically change the Transition property of the TransitioningContentControl depending on which direction you are navigating.